# Cherry picking properties in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, syntax, coffeescript

Is there a way in CoffeeScript to reduce the code size but still have the same effect as -

```
{hours, seconds, minutes} = data
x = {hours, seconds, minutes}
```

Comment: You can do it with [underscore pick method](http://underscorejs.org/#pick): `x = _.pick data, 'hours', 'seconds', 'minutes'`.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny using an external library is the only option?

Comment: `x = { hours: data.hours, seconds: data.seconds, minutes: data.minutes }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do it.

The best one is to adopt some helpful library, e.g. [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](http://lodash.com/):

```
x = _.pick data, 'hours', 'seconds', 'minutes'
```

But if you don't want to include external library to your project, then you may use one of the following methods.

Function call:

```
x = (->{@hours, @seconds, @minutes}).call data
```

Define custom reusable pick method:

```
Object::pick = (args...) ->
  res = {}
  res[k] = @[k] for k in [].concat args
  res

x = data.pick 'hours', 'seconds', 'minutes'
```

Comment: the second option look really neat. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In ES6, one idiom is

```
(({hours, seconds, minutes}) => ({hours, seconds, minutes})) (data)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  deconstruct argument           return object constructed 
  into variables                 using object literal
                                 shorthand
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^
                    DEFINE FAT ARROW FUNCTION                CALL IT
```

Whether you think is is good or horrible is ultimately a matter of personal preference.

What we really need is a `pick` operator in the language, so I could write

```
{hours, seconds, minutes} PICK data
```

For this [I am proposing `#`](http://rtm.github.io/boberator.html), so

```
{hours, seconds, minutes} # data
```

Related: [One-liner to take some properties from object in ES 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553910/one-liner-to-take-some-properties-from-object-in-es6/25554551#25554551)