# Filter JSON data by property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON serialized collection:

```
[
    {
        "_id":"person1",
        "date":"7/20/2014 17:20:09",
        "listed_name":"Tom",
        "name":"Tom",
        "contact_info":"tom@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "_id":"person2",
        "date":"7/20/2014 17:20:09",
        "listed_name":"Jane",
        "name":"Jane",
        "contact_info":"Person2@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "_id":"person3",
        "date":"7/20/2014 17:20:09",
        "listed_name":"John",
        "name":"John",
        "contact_info":"Person3@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

And property name information coming from another page...

```
["_id", "date", "listed_name"]
```

The questions is...

Using JavaScript, how can I use the second array as a filter to return only the columns contained in the second array?

For instance: using this array `["_id"]`... how can this array be used to only show the `_id` data for all JSON objects but keep out `date`, `listed_name`, `name`, etc...?

With the `["_id"]` array as a filter, the expected console output should look like this:

```
person1
person2
person3
```

Comment: As JSON is a string of platform independent, serialized data; and as you did not tag a language, I'll ask--into what language will you be unserializing this JSON data and attempting the manipulation about which you ask?

Comment: Have you tried anything thus far? Show us the code you've attempted, please.

Comment: ive tried quite a few different things. but give me a second to go back and look.

Comment: should i put the attempted code in here? or in the main question?

Comment: You should at least show an example of the expected output.  Your explanation is helpful, but an example speaks volumes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have your incoming JSON in a variable.

```js
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(inputJSON)
var filterArray = ["_id", "date"]

for (var i = 0; i < parsedJSON.length; ++i) {
    for (var filterItem in filterArray) {
        console.log(parsedJSON[i][filterArray[filterItem]])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you define a little helper function called `pick` (or use underscore's `_.pick`) to pick out specified properties from an object, then in ES6 it's just

```
input . map(element = > pick(element, fields))
```

In English, with bold words associated with the code above:

> Take the **input** and **map** each **element** in it to the result of **picking** from that **element** some specified **fields**.

or using array comprehensions

```
[ for (elt of input) pick(elt, fields) ]
```

or in ES5

```
input . map(function(elt) { return pick(elt, fields); })
```

How do you write `pick`? If you're writing in ES6 then

```
function pick(o, fields) {
    return Object.assign({}, ...(for (p of fields) {[p]: o[p]}));
}
```

See [One-liner to take some properties from object in ES 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553910/one-liner-to-take-some-properties-from-object-in-es6/25554551#25554551). That question also provides some non-ES6 alternatives, such as

```
function pick(o, fields) {
    return fields.reduce(function(result, field) {
        result[field] = o[field];
        return result;
    }, {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would deserialize the array, then use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the result and within the map function loop over each of the items in the array of identifiers you want to keep, copying them to a new object, and returning that from the map. So in pseudocode:

```
var filters = [/* our array of identifiers to keep */];
var filtered = JSON.parse(unfiltered).map(function(currObj) {
  var temp = {};
  for identifier in filters:
    temp[identifier] = currObj[identifier];
  return temp;
});
```

This gives you your array of now filtered objects in the `filtered` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyones help but I figured out a solution. Might not be the most efficient... don't know ... but it works. Here is the code in its entirety.

```
    $.getJSON( '/jsonData', function(data) {

            //Put JSON list data into variable.
            listData = data;
            //Get external query array.
            var parsedArray = JSON.parse([storedArray]); //console output:["_id", "date", "listed_name"]
            //Loop through parsedArray to get filters.
            for(var i=0;i<parsedArray.length;i++){
                //Put array items into variable.
                queryKeys = parsedArray[i];
                //Loop through all JSON data.
                for(var x=0;x<ListData.length;x++){
                    //filter output by queryKeys variable.
                    console.log(makerListData[x][queryKeys]);
                }
    });
```

console output:

```
person1
person2
person3
7/20/2014 17:20:09
7/20/2014 17:20:09
7/20/2014 17:20:09
Tom
Jane
John
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a library, [lodash](https://lodash.com/) makes this trivial:

```
function pick(collection, attributes) {
  return _(attributes)
    .map(function(attr) { return _.pluck(collection, attr); })
    .flatten()
    .value();
}
```

Examples:

```
pick(data, ['_id']);
// -> ["person1", "person2", "person3"]

pick(data, ['_id', 'date', 'listed_name']);
// -> ["person1", "person2", "person3", "7/20/2014 17:20:09", "7/20/2014 17:20:09", "7/20/2014 17:20:09", "Tom", "Jane", "John"]
```