# Object property assignment with destructuring?

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, ecmascript-6

I'd like to use [ES6 destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to assign properties of an object, but can't figure out the syntax.

<= ES5:

```
var dst = {};  // already in existence, with its own props, methods, etc.
var src = { a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz' };
dst.a = src.a;
dst.b = src.b;
```

>= ES6 (my own made-up, not-working syntax):

```
let dst = {};
let src = { a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz' };
dst[{a, b}] = src;
```

Is it possible to use destructuring assignment onto an object? What's the correct syntax?

**EDIT:** In my use case, `dst` is an object that existed well before needing to merge a subset of `src`'s properties; it is not a new Object created solely to 'borrow' from `src`.

Comment: This doesn't look much like destructuring to me, you could have just cloned the item.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553910/one-liner-to-take-some-properties-from-object-in-es6; that question is not asking about assigning to one object a subset of properties from another, it's asking about creating a new object from a subset of properties from another. I'll edit my question to clarify that.

Comment: @MinusFour I can't just clone or `Object.assign()`, because I don't want all of `src`'s properties. In my example, note I'm leaving behind `c: 'baz'`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you’re going to have to repeat `dst`:

```
({a: dst.a, b: dst.b} = src);
```

Comment: I tried this, but didn't have the parens around it. That caused a syntax error -- I now understand that was because the destructuring assignment was interpreted instead as an object literal. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried this in node v5.6 with `--harmony_shipping` and it doesn't appear to work - "Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

Comment: @Alnitak: V8 doesn’t support all of ES6. Works in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest approach IMO is as follows:

```
const dist = {a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz'};

const {a, b} = dist;

const src = {a, b};
```

run the example in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/laurengreenway/pen/VqYWOW?editors=0001)