# Can I write block of code shorter using ES6/ES7

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I have a block of code:

```
const {address, cityDistrict, city, country} = data;

const obj = {
  location: {address, cityDistrict, city, country}
};
```

But can I write this one shorted? I tried this one, but it's wrong:

```
const obj = {
  location: {address, cityDistrict, city, country} = data
};
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You'd have to do something like this `location: {address: data.address, cityDistrict: data.cityDistrict, city: data.city, country: data.country}`...

Comment: It appears to be working for me in chrome? What is your error specifically? Is it browser specific?

Comment: Works for me, what are you testing it on?

Comment: Does data contain more than those properties?

Comment: this question comes up almost every day. why are people so concerned with making their code clever? The working code you provided is readable and expresses intentions very clearly.

Comment: @zeroflagL yes, lots of properties.

Comment: @naomik There really is something inelegant about duplicating property names though. The language could do with a `_.pick` equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>This will not work using the es2015 preset, but will work using es2016.</del>

<del>Trying this in https://babeljs.io/repl illustrates this.</del>

**Updated**

The [answer from CodingIntrigue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082954/can-i-write-block-of-code-shorter-using-es6-es7/40083948#40083948) shows why this one does not work.

I also think what you want is **currently** not achievable with a *destructuring one-liner*. You'd better stick to your first intent unless you **really** don't want to have some variables assignments, and in such case you'd likely use an *IIFE* to filter keys.

As [zeroflagl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2151351/zeroflagl) said, you can do it using [spread properties](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread/blob/master/Spread.md) if you use ES proposal stage 3.

```
const data = {
  address: 'address',
  cityDistrict: 'district',
  city: 'city',
  country: 'country'
}
const { address, cityDistrict, city, country } = data;

const obj = {
  location: {...data}
};

console.log(obj)

/* logs Object {
  "location": Object {
    "address": "address",
    "city": "city",
    "cityDistrict": "district",
    "country": "country"
  }
}
*/
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is expected behavior - just a side effect of different parsing techniques between the two presets' plugins maybe?

Comment: You're right @CodingIntrigue, and your `You'd get unexpected data. As a side effect of that, you'd also get 4 new variables in scope` says it all. I think the best one-liner we can do would be an immediately invoked function expression using `data` as a parameter to filter the keys. But the result is less understandable than the original code.

Comment: _"what you want is not achievable with a destructuring one-liner."_ If data does not contain additional properties: `location: {...data}`. Stage 3 proposal.

Comment: Nice addition @zeroflagL, I wasn't aware of this. It's worth mentioning [Stage 3 proposal] implementation still does not work on Babel REPL.

Comment: It works. I successfully tested it.

Comment: I can't edit my comment above, but the [rest properties](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread#rest-properties) example won't work with the repl. Spread properties will work though.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 4):

This actually does work (in Chrome at least, in Babel too if you wrap the assignment in parenthesis), but the two pieces of code *are not equivalent*.

The second piece of code simply assigns `data` to the `location` property and creates 4 new variables in scope called `address`, `cityDistrict`, etc.

For example:

```
const data = {
  address: "Address",
  cityDistrict: "District",
  city: "City",
  country: "Country"
}

const obj = {
  location: ({address, cityDistrict, city, country} = data)
};
console.log(obj);
```

Looks like it logs the correct data, but what is actually printing is `data`, **not new object**. So if we do something like this:

```
const obj = {
  location: ({address, cityDistrict, city, country} = data)
};

data.address = "Test"

console.log(obj); // location.Address = Test
```

You'd get unexpected data. As a side effect of that, you'd also get 4 new variables in scope:

```
const obj = {
  location: ({address, cityDistrict, city, country} = data)
};

console.log(address, cityDistrict, city, country); // All defined
```

What you really want to do is to use `Object.assign` to create a new instance of an object:

```
const obj = {
    location: Object.assign({}, data);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer, but I can't do `Object.assign({}, data)` because I have lots of unused data inside `data`

Comment: @rel1x I understand. I usually use [lodash.pick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.pick) or [this native implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553910/one-liner-to-take-some-properties-from-object-in-es-6)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy data you can use it:

```
const obj = {location: Object.assign({}, data)}
```

Or you also can use next code, but changing obj.location can change data:

```
const obj = {location: data}
```