# Using object assign to delete properties that are different -ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

Below are 2 objects what I want is Object.assign(initalPlan, data), but I want to delete the fields also that are not provided in data.

```
const initialPlan = {
        default_plan: false,
        external_plan_id: fakeString,
        public_available: true,
        name: fakeString,
        price: fakeNumber,
        pricing_period: fakeNumber,
        pricing_period_unit: fakeString,
        space_limit: fakeNumber,
        staff_max_limit: fakeNumber,
        staff_min_limit: fakeNumber,
        trial_period: fakeNumber,
        trial_period_unit: fakeString,
    };
```

and other object:

```
const data = {
            external_plan_id: plan.external_plan_id,
            space_limit: plan.space_limit,
            staff_min_limit: plan.staff_min_limit,
            staff_max_limit: plan.staff_max_limit,
            file_storage_limit: plan.file_storage_limit,
            file_storage_limit_unit: plan.file_storage_limit_unit,
            default_plan: plan.default_plan,
        };
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't, `object.assign` does not delete properties, all it does is a shallow copy of the properties in the sources to the target. You most likely want to iterate and manually copy properties instead.

Comment: You could override the Object.assign function to do what you want. But you definitely shouldn't. What you should do is write a function that uses hasOwnProperty ? copyValue : null.

Comment: Do you absolutely *want* to update the properties `initialData`? If you assigned a new object you could use a [pick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553910/one-liner-to-take-some-properties-from-object-in-es-6) function.

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Do you want to copy properties from `data` to `initialPlan` or only delete properties. If it's only the former, then why is `initialPlan` constant? If it's the latter, then why do you talk about `Object.assign`?

Comment: How is what you want to do different than `Object.assign({}, data);`?

Comment: I'm with @torazaburo on this. The result of your desired computation will be exactly equal to `data`.

Comment: @torazaburo you are right, I was trying to make jasmine test as real as I could, but ended up copying the data object for tests. The function is was trying to test, took the plan argument and made PUT with data object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have your `data` and `initialPlan` objects, you can do something like this to remove the properties on `initialPlan` that aren't present on `data`. Then you could use `Object.assign(initialPlan, data)`.

```
const dataKeys = Object.keys(data);
const initialPlanKeys = Object.keys(initialPlan);

initialPlanKeys.forEach(k => {
  if (!dataKeys.includes(k))
    delete initialPlan[k];
});
```

Comment: @torazaburo `Object.assign(initialPlan, data)` right before my code example. Didn't include it in the code block because the OP stated that's what he was trying to use.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `Object.assign` and remove all the keys that are not part of data

```js
const initialPlan = {
  key1: 1,
  key2: 2,
  key3: 3
}
const data = {
  key1: 10,
  key2: 0
}

Object.assign(initialPlan, data);
Object.keys(initialPlan).forEach(function(key){
   if(!data.hasOwnProperty(key)) delete initialPlan[key];
});
console.log(initialPlan)
```

Comment: Why not just remove **all** keys from `initialPlan` to start with?

Comment: @torazaburo that was my initial thought but he could be using that `initialPlan` and that `data` could be just to update it