# Is there a better/shorter pattern for setting a subset of an object's properties on another object?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to determine if there is any better/shorter way of taking a subset of the properties on an object and adding (only) those properties to another object.  Obviously this isn't the most important thing in the world, but since I do this sort of thing fairly often it would be nice to figure out the ideal pattern for it.

Let's say I have an object, eg.

```
const cheesyRecipes = {
    cheesyBread: ...,
    grilledCheeseSandwich: ...,
    macAndCheese: ...,
    ...
}
```

and I want to apply a subset of that object on to another object, eg.

```
const cheesyBreadRecipes = {};
// do something with cheesyRecipes?
cheesyBreadRecipes; // == {cheesyBread, grilledCheeseSandwich}
```

I see a few ways I can do it.  I can go the old school way ...

```
const cheesyRecipesWithBread = [`cheesyBread`, `grilledCheeseSandwhich`];
for(var i = 0; i < cheesyRecipesWithBread.length; i++) {
    const recipeName = cheesyRecipesWithBread[i];
    cheesyBreadRecipes[recipeName] = cheesyRecipes[recipeName];
});
```

or I can get a little fancier and use `reduce` ...

```
[`cheesyBread`, `grilledCheeseSandwhich`].reduce((memo, recipeName) => {
    memo[recipeName] = cheesyRecipes[recipename];
    return memo;
}, cheesyBreadRecipes);
```

or I can get even fancier and halve the line count by using ES6 destructuring ...

```
const {cheesyBread, grilledCheeseSandwhich} = cheesyRecipes;
Object.apply(cheesyBreadRecipes, {cheesyBread, grilledCheeseSandwhich});
```

But even that last one, which is clearly the shortest, seems to violate the DRY principle by repeating every recipe's name on both lines.  So, my question is, is there any clever way I can use destructuring (or anything else for that matter) to apply a subset of one object's properties on to another, without having to repeat each property twice?  Or is my last example as good as it gets?

Comment: Not 100% sure if this is exactly what you were after, but you might take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/25553910/3123195

Comment: Good catch: that question seems to be the same as this one (and they seemed to reach the same conclusions reached here).  I'll flag mine as a duplicate, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a library is OK, then pick could be shorter.

`ver newObj = _.pick(oldObj, ['cheesyBread', 'grilledCheeseSandwhich'])`

[Docs on lodash pick](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#pick)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that actually seems longer.  Consider: `const {cheesyBread, grilledCheeseSandwhich} = cheesyRecipes; Object.apply(cheesyBreadRecipes, {cheesyBread, grilledCheeseSandwhich});` vs. `const cheesyBreadRecipes = _.pick(cheesyRecipes, ['cheesyBread', 'grilledCheeseSandwhich']); Object.apply(cheesyBreadRecipes, cheesyBreadRecipes);` (you can't really see it in the comments, but if you paste that in to an editor you'll see the `_.pick` is longer).  It definitely is better though in terms of how it doesn't violate DRY by requiring the object keys twice.