# clone particular keys from Object ES6 way

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, key, clone

What is the ES6 (ES2015) way to create new object from particular keys 
without repeat the keys twise.

for example:

```
var orginalObject= {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4}
// not working
var extractedObj = { orginalObject.a , orginalObject.b} // extractedObj == {a:1, b:2}
```

I ask that because EC6 as a lot of new shiny ways to copy and create objects

Comment: It is simple enough already. Nothing special in ES2015 that could make it more concise (in terms of characters or statements number).

Comment: What made you think ES6 would offer anything to "simplify" that?

Comment: @FelixKling Although not mentioned at within text of Question, OP is getting syntax error using pattern at Question, no?

Comment: @guest271314: That's correct.

Comment: @FelixKling Utilizing default value `var {newObj = {a:oldObj.a, b:oldObj.b}} = {}` http://stackoverflow.com/a/41113795/

Comment: @guest271314: Why would that be any better/simpler than doing `var newObj = {a:oldObj.a, b:oldObj.b};` directly? To me it's the opposite.

Comment: @FelixKling Good point. Does the same hold for linked Question? Or, is there a different expectation there?

Comment: @FelixKling Re-marked the Question as duplicate too prematurely, here. The difference between the two Questions: _"How one can write a function"_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553910/one-liner-to-take-some-properties-from-object-in-es-6 . If the present Question is a duplicate, it is not of the linked Question.

Comment: @guest271314 it is much more simpler when key's object is too long. like in my real use case : `{startAnimation:orginal.startAnimation, endAnimation:orginal.endAnimation)` instead of (for example):`{orginal.startAnimation,orginal.endAnimation)`

Comment: @FelixKling because the EC6 provide a lot of new shiny ways to copy and move properties from objects and arrays

Comment: @perymimon _"it is much more simpler when key's object is too long"_ What do you mean by "it"? Not sure what you are trying to convey?

Comment: @guest271314 not repeat the keys twise . to define the key and to extract it from the orginal object

Comment: @guest271314 thank, point taken

Answer (score 3):

You could make it really sharp and ES6-y with multiple `let` statements.

```js
let oldObj = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4},
    newObj
{
    let {a, b} = oldObj
    newObj = {a, b}
}

console.log(newObj) //=> { a:1, b:2 }
```

Or just opt for the simpler ES5 version:

```js
var oldObj = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}
var newObj = {a: oldObj.a, b: oldObj.b}

console.log(newObj) //=> { a:1, b:2 }
```

Comment: I just fixed that wording, you read my mind. "Sharp and ES6-y" is a better description. Maybe "edgy" would be best.

Comment: It will however pollute the current scope.

Comment: it nice, but that is the best way to achieve that ?

Comment: @perymimon What is the definition of "best" as applied in this case? Which options are you comparing when evaluating which is "best"? How can another user determine what is "best" for your "real use case" where `javascript` representing the real use case does not appear at original Question?

Comment: @perymimon: These are the two best ways I can think of. Honestly, I would probably choose the second; using ES6 object destructuring doesn't seem to make your resulting code much terser or more readable.