# Javascript Functional - Better way to get some object properties

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

is there a better way to do this? I want return specific properties from object. This way works but i thinking that is not the best way.

```
target.formats.map(format => {
  const {
    id,
    format_type_id,
    payment_type,
    initial_date,
    final_date,
    estimated_audience,
    direction_type_id,
    price
  } = format

  return {
    id,
    format_type_id,
    payment_type,
    initial_date,
    final_date,
    estimated_audience,
    direction_type_id,
    price
  }
})
```

Comment: Thats a weird code

Comment: This is the point. ;)

Comment: See [One-liner to take some properties from object in ES 6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25553910/3853934)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do it in a very straightforward manner *without* destructuring assignment

```
target.formats.map(f => ({
  f.id,
  f.format_type_id,
  f.payment_type,
  f.initial_date,
  f.final_date,
  f.estimated_audience,
  f.direction_type_id,
  f.price
})
```

Or you could write a generic function which picks certain properties

```
const props = xs => y => {
  let acc = {}
  for (let x of xs) acc[x] = y[x]
  return acc;
}

target.formats.map(props([
  'id',
  'format_type_id',
  'payment_type',
  'initial_date',
  'final_date',
  'estimated_audience',
  'direction_type_id',
  'price'
]))
```

Comment: First approach is great! I'd use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the deconstruction in the parameter list with some extra parentheses.

```
target.formats.map(({ id, format_type_id /* ... */ }) => ({ id, format_type_id /* ... */ }));
```

Comment: But then you have to write the list of properties twice

Comment: @fafl, yes, obviously.

Comment: I don't see how it resolve duplication problem... :/

Comment: it does not. it moves the variables to the parameter part. anyway, you need some indicator which parts should be included in the new object. either by iteration and an array, like [Toni's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41465676/1447675) or [fafl's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41464829/1447675) answers or with your deconstructuring, or mine *without the need of `format` variable*.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to return only specific attributes from an object? Try this:

```js
var bigObj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}

function keepProperties(props, obj) {
  var result = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
    var prop = props[i]
    result[prop] = obj[prop]
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(keepProperties(["a", "c"], bigObj))
```

So you can run something like

```
target.formats.map(f => keepProperties(["id", "format_type_id"], f))
```

Comment: Let's not replace standard [language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) [features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) with less powerful custom code. (Also a nice overview of destructuring may be found [here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html)).

Comment: I don't think these features are a good fit here

Comment: @user268396 how destructuring can resolve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Why not create a method on your object to return it in your format?

```js
//Define object rules
var myClass = (function() {
  function myClass() {
    this.a = 1;
    this.date = new Date();
  }
  myClass.prototype.format = function() {
    return {
      a: this.a,
      d: this.date
    };
  };
  return myClass;
}());
//Create an object
var obj = new myClass();
//Log in format
console.log(obj.format());
```

Comment: Let's not replace standard [language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) [features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) with less powerful custom code. (Also a nice overview of destructuring may be found [here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html)).

Comment: @user268396 destructuring and spread are good features, but not entirely cross browser compatible so alternatives to language features is relevant.

Comment: @user268396 the object has 15 properties. How this link can resolve the problem?