# ES6 destructuring within a return statement

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Is it possible to destructure an object while returning it at the same time.
For example, to change this code:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ newItem }) =>{
  const { id, name, price } = newItem;
  return { id, name, price };
}
```

To something like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ newItem }) =>{
  return { id, name, price } = newItem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply Pointy, and yes of course I have tried it but with so much syntactic sugar in ES6, I thought there may be a correct way of doing it

Comment: Your code works already, not sure what "correct way of doing it" you want.

Comment: @kfcobrien well if you tried it, what happened? That sort of information helps people understand more about your question and the specifics of what you're attempting to do.

Comment: it returns an "id is not defined" error

Comment: @Oriol No, it really doesn't. It does assign global variables and returns the object from the argument.

Comment: OK, the codes are not equivalent, but the second one destructures an object and returns it, like asked in the description.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

*(Disclaimer: your syntax works and does both destructuring and returning, but it is equivalent to*

```
({ id, name, price } = newItem); // assigns global variables
return newItem;
```

*which is probably not what you wanted)*

To do what you want (which I assume is creating a new object), you need to use an **object literal** (potentially with shorthand property notation). See also [One-liner to take some properties from object in ES 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25553910/1048572):

```
const mapStateToProps = ({newItem: {id, name, price}}) => ({id, name, price});
```

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!! Sorry I was not clearer in my description :)

Comment: Nice. So for example, I want to assign a copy of `newItem` and pick only some of the props, I can do it in one line: `const newItemCopy = (({name, price}) => ({name, price}))(newItem)`

Comment: in case someone needs good instructions on destructuring please go here : [link](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-object-destructuring/)

Answer (score 3):

In ES6 you can also do the following, if you want to pass all the `newItem` keys

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ newItem }) => ({ ...newItem });
```

Comment: This works when all properties should be returned. But when specific properties needs to be returned, the first approach suits better.

Comment: That's exactly the same as just returning `newItem` if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: They're not the same, returning newItem returns a reference to the newItem property on the original object where this returns a new object with the properties that newItem had.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/calebwheeler/pen/oNWddVP)

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do what you want without this repetition.

But this require the usage of forbidden js feature; and this isn't destructuring anymore.

So I would not recommend it at all.

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ newItem }) =>{
  with (newItem) {
   return { id, name, price };
  }
}
```

Comment: The use of `with` is no longer recommended . Refer this for better understanding:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend another approach to achieve the same result.

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ newItem }) =>{
  return {
    id: newItem.id,
    name: newItem.name,
    price: newItem.price
  };
}
```

Or shorter:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ newItem: i }) =>{
  return {
    id: i.id,
    name: i.name,
    price: i.price
  };
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({newItem: i}) => ({
  id: i.id, name: i.name, price: i.price
})
```

Here are some reasons why this would be better:

- It has an added flexibility to rename properties easily if needed.
- It is short and simple. Quite easy to read.
- It has better performance over destructuring at least on some browsers: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/22226/0/creating-a-partial-object-destructuring-vs-property-pic

Comment: Question was "is it possible" not how performant is it

Comment: That is true. Reasoning: I added the performance analysis to support the fact that it's better not to use destructuring in this case. I stumbled upon your question when my goal was practically the same. I wanted to remove the duplication. After analysing my options I ended up to do the above. I added the answer to help people in similar situation and offer a best practice to practically do the same. If the question was purely theoretical I apologise. I should move the answer elsewhere.

Comment: @kfcobrien If you don't consider this answer valuable I can remove it. Do you think I should?