# Destructuring in a return statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, relay

I have multiple cases throughout my app that look something like this:

```
  getVariables() {
    const {
      allowCustomValues,
      budgets,
      budgetsToAdd,
      budgetsToRemove,
      isGlobal,
      isRequired,
      name,
      tagTypeId,
      valuesToAdd,
      valuesToDelete,
    } = this.props;

    return {
      allowCustomValues,
      budgets,
      budgetsToAdd,
      budgetsToRemove,
      isGlobal,
      isRequired,
      name,
      tagTypeId,
      valuesToAdd,
      valuesToDelete,
    };
  }
```

This seems very cumbersome, but the shorter solution involves preceding every variable I want with `this.props.`, which isn't really better from a maintenance standpoint.

What I'd like is something like:

```
  getVariables() {
    return this.props.{
      allowCustomValues,
      budgets,
      budgetsToAdd,
      budgetsToRemove,
      isGlobal,
      isRequired,
      name,
      tagTypeId,
      valuesToAdd,
      valuesToDelete,
    };
  }
```

Is there some kind of ES6 syntax that allows me to make this code a bit more DRY?

EDIT:
Possibly a duplicate of [ES6 destructuring within a return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794086/es6-destructuring-within-a-return-statement?rq=1), but that one has an accepted answer that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: No, there is not. There are various proposals though.

Comment: https://github.com/rbuckton/proposal-shorthand-improvements, https://github.com/rtm/js-pick-notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually destructuring does not allow that.

You are asking about equivalent for lodash's [`pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#pick). Maybe you have already lodash in you project. If you don't you still can write such a helper on your own(but better use stable community-proved versio from lodash or another library)

Comment: Well, this is actually a very good answer, as we do have Lodash, thanks!

Comment: It's probably worth noting, however, that this method isn't going to get checked by a linter, and is much less efficient due to the creation of so many string literals.

Comment: But it's not exactly lodash's pick() because using pick you still have to repeat yourself, both while destructing each prop + assigning all props to a single var.

Comment: @RegarBoy not sure about _your_ case, OP asked to destructure object only to return smaller subset of keys. Sure, if you need to do additional operations with every or some properties, `_.pick` will not be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `Object.assign()`?

```
    return Object.assign({}, this.props);
```

That'll build a new empty object and then copy all the enumerable properties from `this.props` into it. The target object is returned by `Object.assign()` so it pretty much does all the work.

Answer (score 1):

How about

`return {...this.props}`

Comment: What if I don't want all of the props, just specific ones? That's the entire point of destructuring.