# ES6 Spread Operator clone or extract specific keys to another object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to clone an object with specified keys. For example you have this object

```
const User = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  age: '',
  gender: '',
  job: '',
}
```

and you just want to clone or extract the `firstName` and `lastName` to create another object like:

```
const UserPublicInfo = {
  firstName,
  lastName,
}
```

I know a few solutions but...

### Solution #1: Manual

```
const UserPublicInfo = {
  firstName: User.firstName,
  lastName: User.lastName,
}
```

### Caveat

There is no problem with a small list but this is going to be tedious with a large list, let's say 10+ keys or more.

### Solution #2: Rest Operator

We can omit the keys specifically with Rest Operator

```
const { firstName, lastName, ...UserPublicInfo } = User
```

### Caveat

This is easier than the first solution but the problem is what if you don't know the properties of the `User` object? Yes you can `console.log` the content but what if later in your development a team mate has updated this `User` object and decided to add another property, your app will mostly like cause errors along the way. So security-wise `Solution #1` is better.

I was hoping it could be done easy like in the following code but it throws error on my transpiler.

```
const UserPublicInfo = { firstName, lastName } = User
```

Are there better solutions out there for this use-case?

Comment: This question has been asked many times. The term usually used for this operation is "picking", so you could search for that. The basic answer is no, there is no easy, direct way. You could check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553910/one-liner-to-take-some-properties-from-object-in-es-6/25835337#25835337.

Comment: method 2 doesn't look valid (babel doesn't like it at all)

Comment: BTW this is not the "rest operator"; the correct term is "object rest properties". See https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37152508/218196)

Comment: Probably the most concise way to pick keys out of an object explicitly is to do it with an array.

Comment: Probably the most concise way to pick keys explicitly from an object with a long list is to do it with an Array.

function picked(obj,array) {  
  var retr={};  
  array.every(k=>retr[k]=obj[k]);  
  return retr;  
}

I know there is a way to use reduce to make that a one liner.  But having your client code be simple should be enough.

You don't have to use ES6 for every problem that's already been solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can see [this](https://github.com/anetegithub/geranium/blob/master/geranium/runtime/reflection/cloning/concrete/ClonerAssign.ts) [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) implementation (but ES6 capability) of cloning, the idea of `Object.Assign()` and deep-cloning by `Function.prototype.apply`:

```
export class ClonerAssign<T> implements interfaces.ICloner{
        clone<T>(sample: T): T {
            var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(sample);
            //soft clone
            var _new = Object.assign({}, sample, proto, Object.getPrototypeOf(proto));

            //deep clone
            var _props = props(proto).filter(x => notCoreFunc(x));
            _props.forEach(key => {
                if (typeof proto[key] === 'function') {
                    (_new as any)[key] = (...args: any[]) => {
                        (proto[key] as any).apply(_new, args);
                    };
                }
            });

            return _new;
        }
    }
```