# snippet for creating object from destructured array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

For example, I had an array with 3 numbers:

```
var arr = [124, -50, 24];
```

and I need to convert this array to the object:

```
{
   x: 124,
   y: -50,
   z: 24
}
```

I don`t want to use "old-style" syntax for this, for example:

```
{
  x: arr[0],
  y: arr[1],
  z: arr[2]
}
```

so for now, I`m using that syntax:

```
const [x, y, z] = [...arr];
const obj = {x, y, z};
```

But, is there is any way to do this with a straight dectructuring array to object without need of temporary variables?

Comment: off the top of my head `var obj = (([x,y,z]) => ({x,y,z}))(arr);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45971203/1048572?

Comment: @Bergi, there's no array -> object in that question ... is there?

Comment: @JaromandaX It's about "renaming" properties, like from `0` to `x` - whether it's an array object or plain object doesn't make much difference, the choices for destructuring and literal syntax are the same.

Comment: I think this is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242744/destructure-array-to-object-property-keys

Comment: ahhh yes @bergi, I see that now ... I think :p

Comment: @JaromandaX In any case, I answered rather than closing as a duplicate. It's not totally obvious indeed.

Comment: @llama - similar? identical!!!

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks, that works! It remains only to understand what is going on there :)

Comment: @JaromandaX: simidentical? identilar?

Comment: @llama - yes you right! I missed that question :( But the best answer there is getting array values by indexes. I have mentioned in my question that is not what im looking for

Comment: `It remains only to understand what is going on there` @VladPovalii it's an IIFE of the arrow function `([x,y,z]) => ({x,y,z})`. But imo you should store this function `const arr2point = ([x,y,z]) => ({x,y,z});` and use that `const obj = arr2point(arr)` instead of using the IIFE inline.

Comment: Why do people always try to use  destructuring to build an object ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was already mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46426557/snippet-for-creating-object-from-destructured-array/56319911#comment79810448_46426557) you can use an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to create the object in a single step, but it's less readable then multiple steps.

```js
const arr = [124, -50, 24];
const obj = (([x, y, z]) => ({ x, y, z }))(arr);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: lol. I've changed the sorting order by mistake, and this question popped. I've answered it like it was new (not really looked at the comments), and totally forgot about it.

Comment: :) Anyway its ok..finally this question will have the right answer, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
const obj = {};
([obj.x, obj.y, obj.z] = arr);
```

to avoid the temporary variables, but I'd question whether that's an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this

```
let obj = {...arr}
```

Comment: Not quite right, because you want to control the object keys naming ("x", "y", "z") - but after this keys will be: "0", "1", "2"