# ES6 curly braces usage when extracting from an object and assigning to another object

Tags: ecmascript-6, curly-braces

I would like to use curly braces to replace this code:

```
let rUsers = children.map((user) => {
    let rUser= {};
    rUser.firstName = user.firstName;
    rUser.lastName = user.lastName;
    rUser.relation = user.patron.relation;
    return rUser;
 });
```

This is what I have:

```
let rUsers = children.map((user) => {
    let rUser = {};
    ({
        firstName: rUser.firstName,
        lastName: rUser.lastName,
        patron.relation: rUser.relation, // I get an error here
    } = user);
    return rUser;
}
```

Except for patron.relation, the rest of the extraction works.

Questions:

1. How should I extract value of user.patron.relation?
2. Is there a more succint way of writing the above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I extract value of `user.patron.relation`?

You would use `{ … patron: {relation: rUser.relation}, … }` as the destructuring target.

> Is there a more succint way of writing the above?

If the property names don't match [there's not much you can do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45971411/1048572), but in your particular case you can simplify by destructuring the parameter into multiple variables:

```
const rUsers = children.map(({firstName, lastName, patron: {relation}}) => 
    ({firstName, lastName, relation})
);
```

Comment: Thanks @Bergi for answering both ! Worked well!

In cases where properties can't be passed as parameters,  how would you extract specific properties from one object and assign them to another object?

Comment: @fab What do you mean by "properties that can't be passed as parameters"?

Comment: in the above, we were able to access array's map() method, and pass the object properties as parameters. How about if there's an object user:

      `let user = {
          firstname: 'Aldrin',
          lastname: 'Theo',
          patron: {
              relation: 'Spouse'
          }
      }` 


and we want to extract `firstname` and `patron.relation` into an object `reducedUser`. How would you destructure that?

Comment: @fab Either just destructure into a `let`/`const` and then build the object, or [do all in one IIFE expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25553910/1048572) (with parameters :-P)

Comment: Okay. Thanks @Bergi!

Answer (score 1):

You can use object destructuring like this:

```
const {firstName, lastName, patron: {relation}} = user
```

And `relation` has been set to the value of `user.patron.relation`.

You can return the object you want like so:

```
return {firstName, lastName, relation}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a few things wrong with your code.

1. `patron.relation` -> `patron` isn't defined, and can't be used as a key.
2. In the second example, `rUser` is used - I think you just want `user`.

My understanding of what you're trying to do essentially create a clone? If so, you should be able to do something like this.

```
let rUsers = children.map(user => {
    firstName: user.firstName,
    lastName: user.lastName,
    relation: user.relation
});
```

Alternatively, it could be simpler to use `Object.assign()`

```
let rUsers = children.map(user => Object.assign({}, user));
```