# Assigning to new variable while simultaneously using destructuring assignment

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

ES6 introduced the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax that supports unpacking values from objects:

```
let { r = 0, g = 0, b = 0 } = { r: 255, g: 55 };
let color = { r, g, b };
console.log(color, r, g, b);  // prints "{r: 255, g: 55, b: 0} 255 55 0"
```

However, the following snippet would not have the same effect:

```
let color = { r = 0, g = 0, b = 0 } = { r: 255, g: 55 }
console.log(color);  // prints "{r: 255, g: 55}"
```

Same if you reverse the order:

```
let { r = 0, g = 0, b = 0 } = color = { r: 255, g: 55 }
console.log(color);  // prints "{r: 255, g: 55}"
```

Is there a one-line solution to assign `r`, `g`, `b`, along with `color`?

Comment: No, creating a new object always requires an object literal. See also [One-liner to take some properties from object in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25553910/1048572). Your two-line version is just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Object.assign()` first to create full color object (including all 3 parts of it), assign the result to `color` variable and apply the destructing on it:

```
let { r, g, b } = color = Object.assign({ r: 0, b: 0, g: 0 }, { r: 255, g: 55 });
console.log(r, g, b, color); // prints "255 55 0 {r: 255, b: 0, g: 55}"
```

Unfortunately this approach will fail in strict mode, as it's trying to assign to undefined `color` variable. One option to solve this, if you are fine with `color` being bound to `window`, is to assign to `window.color` directly (or if you are doing this inside a class/function, you can bound to `this.color` of course).

```js
'use strict';

let { r, g, b } = window.color = Object.assign({ r: 0, b: 0, g: 0 }, { r: 255, g: 55 });

console.log(r, g, b, color); // prints "255 55 0 {r: 255, b: 0, g: 55}"
```

Comment: You don't need the Object.assign - it's equal to `let { r, g, b } = color = {r: 255, g: 55, b: 0 };`. However, the main problem is that `color` becomes a global variable (look at `window.color`). If you'll use 'strict mode', you'll get `color is undefined` error.

Comment: Well the question is also about filling possibly missing key (`b`) with default value, that's the reason for Object.assign (`{r: 255, g: 55}` will be some function parameter or so probably). You are right about the global `color` variable tho...

Answer (score 1):

It's not in the spirit of what you want, but you can always use a comma to write it in a single line:

```js
'use strict';

const { r = 0, g = 0, b = 0 } = { r: 255, g: 55 }, color = { r, g, b };

console.log(color, r, g, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

This does it, but I don't believe it is what you are asking for:

let color = ({ r = 0, g = 0, b = 0 } = { r: 255, g: 55 }, {r, g, b});

As for what I believe you were expecting, I don't think is possible.

Comment: This throws an exception (or creates global variables in sloppy mode) when assigning to the undeclared variables.