# Showing only specific fields of javascript object in the array doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to show specific series of specific fields and value inside of the object but it's not working.

```
var objArray = [
    {id:1, photo:true, bol: true }, {id:2, photo: true, bol:true}
];

result = objArray.map((item) => return {id: item.id, photo: item.photo 
}) // this doesn't work.. why??
```

Expectd Output

```
[
    {id:1, photo:true}, {id:2, photo: true}
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make two changes

- Remove `return` statement - arrow functions will implicitly return the expression's evaluated result.
- Wrap `{}` with `()` so that `{}` doesn't get treated as a code block, but as an expression.

i.e.

```
objArray.map((item) => ({id: item.id, photo: item.photo  }));
```

**Demo**

```js
var objArray = [{
  id: 1,
  photo: true,
  bol: true
}, {
  id: 2,
  photo: true,
  bol: true
}];

var result = objArray.map((item) => ({
  id: item.id,
  photo: item.photo
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: THANKS!! :) great

Comment: Um can I initialize item's value? For example,,, map((item) => let {id, photo} = item; return ({id, photo}); just some thought :)

Comment: wow I've never seen the expression like a { key, key1 } = item; Thanks...

Comment: @JohnBaek my bad, expression that I just gave above doesn't work. You can try this one though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553910/one-liner-to-take-some-properties-from-object-in-es-6

Answer (score 1):

Create temporary Object;

Iterate through object and if key is not "bol", then push it to temp Object;

finally return the temporary Object

```js
var objArray = [
    {id:1, photo:true, bol: true }, {id:2, photo: true, bol:true}
];


result = objArray.map((item) => {
let tempObj = {}
 Object.keys(item).map((key) => {   
   if(key != "bol") {
      tempObj[key] = item[key]
      
   }     
 })
 return tempObj;
 })
 
 console.log(result)
```