# React object manipulation with ES6 spread

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is there a nicer way to do this?:

```
const {
  valueA,
  valueB,
  valueC,
  valueD,
  valueE,
  valueF
} = this.state;

const newObjectWrapper = {
  valueA,
  valueB,
  valueC,
  valueD,
  valueE,
  valueF
};

dispatch(setNewValues(newObjectWrapper));
```

I'm trying to de-structure some of the items in state(not all of them, which is annoying otherwise I could just pass state) and then place them inside a new object so I can group them up before adding them to a store. Is there a nice shorter way to do this?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553910/one-liner-to-take-some-properties-from-object-in-es-6

Comment: Thanks Estus. I used an example from one of your links

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
function whois({ displayName, fullName: {firstName: name} }) {
  console.log(displayName + ' is ' + name);
}

var user = { 
  id: 42, 
  displayName: 'jdoe',
  fullName: { 
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe'
  }
};

whois(user); // "jdoe is John"
```