# Best Practice when converting data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, promise, es6-promise

I'm currently working with a payload that is string and im parsing is using `JSON.parse(payload)`. My question is, once I convert the payload I need to access at least 5 properties within the newly created JSON object and it is quite nested. My current implementation is:

```
 ....then(payload => {
   return ({
       obj1: JSON.parse(payload).field.obj1
       obj2: JSON.parse(payload).field.obj2
       obj3: JSON.parse(payload).field.obj3
       obj4: JSON.parse(payload).field.obj4
       obj5: JSON.parse(payload).field.obj5
     });    
   })
```

I feel like this is to much repetition and feel this way would work better in terms of readability (even then it is not that clean):

```
   ....then(payload => {
       let jsonObj = JSON.parse(payload)
       return ({
           obj1: jsonObj.field.obj1
           obj2: jsonObj.field.obj2
           obj3: jsonObj.field.obj3
           obj4: jsonObj.field.obj4
           obj5: jsonObj.field.obj5
         });    
       })
```

Can anyone suggest the best way to execute this in terms of readability and performance?

NOTE: This is used within a `promise.all()` so the above will iterate over X promises.

Comment: For a start, you should only need to parse the JSON once, then you need to think in terms of populating a model client-side. Start with what you wished you had, then either send that back from the server, or map from the response to what you wished you had.

Comment: Your second approach it's OK, you don't need to do any further stuff.

Comment: Does the `jsonObj.field` contain any other properties?

Comment: Yea it does. @Bergi

Comment: I guess then this becomes a duplicate of [One-liner to take some properties from object in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25553910/1048572). (That you should call `JSON.parse` only once is hopefully obvious)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and return an object with [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```
let { field: { obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5 } } = JSON.parse(payload);
return { obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5 };
```

Comment: That's a lot of repetition, isn't it?

Comment: it depends, actually it looks like that, but  we do not know the original structure.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Better yet, just parse the whole thing and return the field object. I think that would work. (I'm a little sleep deprived though!)

```
....then(payload => {
   return (JSON.parse(payload).field);
})
```

**End Edit**

1. Parse the whole response to find the `field` obj.
2. Stringify the `field` obj to prepare it to be copied.
3. Return the parsed `field` obj.

-

```
....then(payload => {
   return (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(payload).field)));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Bluebird` you can also do (as you already use `Promise.all`)

```
const payloadPromises = Promise.map(sourcePromises, JSON.parse);
return Promise
  .all(payloadPromises)
  .then(payloads => payload.map(payload => ({
    obj1: payload.field.obj1,
    obj2: payload.field.obj2,
  }));
```

But actually just variable (your second approach) is completely fine. Perhaps, you should only use `const` instead of `let` in this case.