# Destructure object properties into array values

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there any way to destructure an object and assign its properties into an array rather than as variables? For example:

```
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };

const { a, b } = obj;
const arr = [a, b];
```

This works, but it requires restating the variables as the array values.

I have tried:

```
const arr = [(const { a, b } = obj)];
```

but this is a syntax error.

I had a similar idea with `Object.values` as in

```
const arr = Object.values((const { red } = chalk));`
```

...but this has the same issue of not being able to do destructuring in expressions.

Comment: Is there a reason not to just use `[obj.a, obj.b]` ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir yes that will work fine, but then I have to type `obj.` a lot if I have a lot of properties to destructure.

Comment: In the second example you only have one property `const arr = Object.values((const { red } = chalk));` why not `const arr = Object.values(chalk.red)`?

Comment: but, do you want to add every property alone the object or like [{a: 1, b : 2}]

Comment: FWIW you can make your original code a *little* more terse: `const { a, b } = obj, arr = [ a, b ];`. You still have to type the names twice, though, and it still introduces two new variables into the local scope.

Comment: As of the first the problem is that the order of properties is not guaranteed. So if there were a syntax to desctruct object to array w/o introducing intermediate variables how would you know the resulting order `[obj.a, obj.b]` vs `[obj.b, obj.a]`

Comment: You can just use [the `with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), oh never mind, nobody is allowed to use that anymore.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko It's my understanding that OP is imagining some syntax where you would specify the names of the properties in the order you want, e.g. `const arr[ b, a ] = { a: 1, b: 2 };`.

Comment: you can do this `[{ a, b} = obj]` but that is the problem of destructuring assignment, it will add to the array an object and not every property as a single

Comment: Ha, you could use default value `const {a, b, arr = [a,b] } = obj`. But if there is `obj.arr` it'll pick the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really the answer you want is to go back in time and use [the `with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) before it was (rightly) recognized as evil:

```
var obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
var arr;
with (obj) {
   arr = [a, b];
}
```

Any modern answer is going to require more typing than you'd like.  A relatively type-safe answer that gets you closer is to use string literals.  Stick this in a library:

```
function arrayDestruct<T, K extends keyof T>(obj:T, ...keys: K[]): T[K][] {
  return keys.map(k => obj[k]);
}
```

And then use it:

```
const arr = arrayDestruct(obj, 'a', 'b'); // recognized as number[]
```

You have to type some quotation marks but it works.  [It could even be overloaded to produce tuples](https://gist.github.com/jcalz/9aa61fc36279f00270c58ffe997bd0af), but I don't know if you really care enough.  Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to destructure an object and assign its properties into an array rather than as variables?

You can do

```
const arr = [];
const { a: arr[0], b: arr[1] } = obj;
```

but I think what you are really looking for is the equivalent to [One-liner to take some properties from object in ES 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25553910/1048572) which with an array literal would be

```
const arr = (({a, b}) => [a, b])(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve that in one hit with destructuring. You have to have one extra line of code.

You can use `Object.values`, but not without losing type fidelity (i.e. you end up with an `Array<any>`.

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    values(obj: {}): any[];
}

const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };

// Array<any>
const arr = Object.values(obj);

// [1, 2]
console.log(arr);
```

So you have a trade off. One line of code in exchange for correct type information seems like the economic win.

```
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const { a, b } = obj;

// Array<number>
const arr = [a, b];

// [1, 2]
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can desconstruct the object like this

```
const [a, b] = Object.values(obj);

console.log(a); // 1
console.log(b); // 2
```

Remember that the keys of the object is not alphabetical, so its perhaps better to create a function which returns the sorted keys, so that you know that the values are set correctly.

```
function deconstructObject(obj){
    const arr = [];  
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    const sortedKeys = keys.sort();
        for(const key of sortedKeys){
            arr.push(obj[key]);
        }
        return arr;
}

const [a, b] = deconstructObject({b: 2, a: 1 });

console.log(a); // 1
console.log(b); // 2

const newArray = deconstructObject({b: 2, a: 1 });
console.log(newArray); //[1,2]
```

Now the object will be sorted, so you can predict its behaviour.

Comment: he wants to use the destructing assignment as a single process. you're not using it. you are using a loop and give it an increase in the complexity... `O(n^2)`