# How to destructure objects with keys names that are numbers?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have props that need to be destructured in a component. As it comes from API, it is actually an object from which I would like to take objects from 0 to 39. However, when I try to destructure them this way:

```
 const { 0, ...39: weatherData } = this.props;
```

VSCode gives me an error of unexpected token because of the comma. How can I destructure the props without having to enumerate every single object?

Comment: Object keys are always strings. Even if those strings contain numeric characters, they are still strings.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, okay, so how to destructure them if I get an error regarding the comma?

Comment: Are you trying to get all the values for a range of keys? I can't tell what you expect the `...` to do here.

Comment: Is this object actually an array? It really should be.

Comment: Even if this wasn't with numeric properties, destructuring doesn't work like that. If you want to create a new object with only a subset of properties, you can do something like https://stackoverflow.com/q/25553910/218196 .

Comment: @loganfsmyth, I was actually trying to spread all the keys not to enumerate them one by one

Comment: @Felix Kling, great, thank you. I did not know that I could actually use this method to destructure them.

Comment: @llievredemars Spread them where? It would help a lot to have some clear example input and output values. The syntax `const {0} =` for instance would try to create a local variable named `0` which isn't allowed, and `...39: weatherData` is also not a thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an empty array as the assignment target for the source object, using `Object.assign`. This method will take only the numerical indices, and then we can `slice` it to the desired length.

```js
const array = Object
    .assign([], { abc: 1, 0: 100, 1: 101, 39: 139, 40: 140 })
    .slice(0, 40); // end number is not inclusive

console.log(Array.isArray(array));
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: But the output is not an array, it's an object.

Comment: slice works only for arrays. please see array check.

Comment: @llievredemars It *should* be an array anyway

Comment: I didn't know/forgot this is how arrays worked. This is much better than my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript even if you created your object using a `number` as a key, the keys are always strings, take the following example:

```js
const obj = {
  [1]: 1,
  anotherThing: 2
};

console.log(Object.keys(obj))
```

However, since `'1'` or `1` are literals, using them in the destructuring assignment is not possible, in order to use the numerical keys you would have to convert your object to `iterable` or map properties manually,

The easiest way to convert your object to iterable is to use `Object.assign` with an array, since an array is also an object you can do the following:

```
const arr = Object.assign([], obj);
```

And to fulfill your purpose, something like:

```js
const obj = {
  [0]: 0,
  [1]: 1,
  wheaterData: 'wheaterData',
  anotherNonNumericProp: '1'
};

const arrOfNumericProps = Object.assign([], obj);

const [prop0, prop1] = arrOfNumericProps;

const {wheaterData,
  ...rest
} = arrOfNumericProps;

console.log(prop0);
console.log(prop1);

console.log(wheaterData);
console.log(rest);
```

Comment: You don't need computed keys for integer-named properties.

Comment: @Bergi no, but it is easier to identify them that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply rename the number variables to string while destructuring to avoid the error:

```
 const { 0:newName, 39:weatherData, ...restOfData } = this.props;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case where I couldn't easily avoid an object with numerical keys.

This was my solution, adapted to your situation:

```js
const props = { 1:'first', 2:'second', /** imagine the keys continue*/ 39: 'thirty-ninth', 40: 'do not want after this', /** imagine the keys continue further*/};
const weatherProps = Object.entries(props).flatMap(([key, value]) => (parseInt(key, 10) <=39 ? [value] : []) );
```

Using `flatMap` is equivalent to a `filter` (reject keys over 39) followed by `map` (from an array to an integer) by (ab)using the fact that empty arrays are 'flattened' out of existence. You could have easily used `reduce` and accumulated only the values you wanted from each entry,  or `Object.values(props).slice(0,39)`  iff you can guarantee the right number of keys.