# Can you dynamically deconstruct an object for usage with currying?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

I've been playing with functional javascript a bit and had an idea for a util function using deconstructing.

Is it possible using `...rest` to pass the names of object keys to later filter out properties?

reading through the ...rest docs I haven't seen any mention of deconstructing.

If not what solution could solve this issue?

```js
const stripObject = attr => ({ ...attr }) => ({ ...attr });

const getUserProps = stripObject(['_id', 'firstName']);

console.log(getUserProps({ _id: 1, firstName: 'foo', lastName: 'bar' }));

/*
I understand right now whats happening is the []
passed is being ignored and its just returning a 
function that passing in all the props 
{
  _id: 1,
  firstName: 'foo'
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After learning what I originally isn't possible solution I ended up using was to reduce over the keys initially passed then grab the prop form the object.

```js
const stripObject = keys => obj => {
  return keys.reduce((p, c) => (
    { ...p, [c]: obj[c] }
  ), {});
};
const getUserProps = stripObject(['_id', 'firstName']);

console.log(getUserProps({
  _id: 1,
  firstName: 'foo',
  lastName: 'bar'
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you like to spread stuff you could spread a specially prepared Proxy :)

```js
const stripObject = attrs => obj => ({ ...new Proxy(obj, {
    ownKeys() {
      return attrs
    }
  })
});

const getUserProps = stripObject(['_id', 'firstName']);

console.log(getUserProps({
  _id: 1,
  firstName: 'foo',
  lastName: 'bar'
}));
```

Comment: Nice! that's awesome I was reading about proxys the other day seem like a really game changer! will have to read up on them more

Comment: @JoeWarner Just keep in mind this answer was made for fun :) Not recommended for production code.

Comment: Oh yeah this was for used for hacking on a side project in testing code but interesting non the less.

Answer (score 1):

`{ ...attr }` in **parameter position** means "get all properties of the passed in object and assign it to a new object assigned to `attr`". I.e. you are just creating a shallow clone of the object that is passed in.

I.e. these two functions are equivalent except for the cloning part

```
({...foo}) => foo
foo => foo
```

So no, what you want is not possible (this way). *You cannot declare parameters dynamically.*

If you want to pull out specific props, you can do adapt this approach ([One-liner to take some properties from object in ES 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25553910/218196)) to your requirements:

```
const stripObject = attr => obj => pick(obj, ...attr);
```

Comment: I mean, technically you can define parameters dynamically by using the `Function` constructor, e.g. `var func = new Function(params.join(','), '...')` but you should not do that ;)