# JS destruct into object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to do this in node js v8

management variable looks like this:

```
let management = {
    ip: '1.1.1.1',
    port: '443',
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'admin'   
}

constructor ({management,system,network,...other}) {

   this.management =  {
      ip ,
      port = 443,
      username = 'admin',
      password = 'admin',
    } = { ...management };
}
```

Any idea why I get the message

ip: ip ,
          ^

ReferenceError: ip is not defined

Shouldn't the evaluation be right to left so management is destructed before trying to assign?
Any idea on how to do this in a clear way without any more code?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: this.management =  {
      ip ,
      port = 443,
      username = 'admin',
      password = 'admin',
    } = { ...management };  in this situation it checks for a variable ip and assign key as ip and value as value assigned to ip, if you need to set empty value to key you need to assign ip: ''

Comment: It tries to assign `ip` variable to the `ip` property, but you don't have that variable.

Comment: That part I got. I was hoping that the destruction of management would do that. Like when you do const { ip } = {...management}

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you destructure into variables that you never declared anywhere, and in strict mode that causes an exception (instead of creating globals).

Btw, you cannot [destructure and construct an object literal at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25553910/1048572). Your code would only assign `{ ...management }` to `this.management` anyway.

You're likely looking for

```
constructor ({management, system, network, ...other}) {
    const {ip, port = 443, username = 'admin', password = 'admin'} = management;
    this.management = {ip, port, username, password};
}
```

or

```
constructor ({management: {ip, port = 443, username = 'admin', password = 'admin'}, system, network, ...other}) {
    this.management = {ip, port, username, password};
}
```

or

```
constructor ({management, system, network, ...other}) {
    this.management = (({ip, port = 443, username = 'admin', password = 'admin'} => ({ip, port, username, password}))(management);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense.

Comment: I went for this const {ip,port,username,password, privateKey} = {...management};
    this.management =  {
      ip ,
      port: port || 443,
      username: username || 'admin',
      password: password || 'admin',
      privateKey,
    }; Since if the future I need to change the proprety name. I think this is clearer to read.

Comment: Don't do `{...management}` when all you need is `management`. No need to create a new object there.

Comment: Yes you are right. I use it because in other places in the code I need to change the prop name for example from ip to host and would prefer to keep everything as consistent as possible.