# Is it possible to destructure an object into existing variables?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring, object-destructuring

I am trying to extract variables using object destructuring but those variables already exist, something like this

```
const x=1, y=2 // Those should be 1 and 2
const {x,y} = complexPoint
const point = {x,y}
```

Is there any way to do this without renaming the destructuring variables?.
Some like this and updating point avoiding `const` definition?

```
const point = {x,y} = complexPoint
```

The expected result should be as using object destructuring

```
const x=1, y=2 // Those should be 1 and 2
const point = {
  x:complexPoint.x,
  y:complexPoint.y
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve there. Are you trying to extract with destructure and then create object?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to extract just those variables

Comment: What's the content of complex point?

Comment: it is a big complex object like `{x,y,z,w,otherFunctions ....}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here it can be done like this.

```js
const complexPoint = {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3};
const simplePoint = ({x, y}) => ({x, y});

const point = simplePoint(complexPoint);

console.log(point);
```

In a single line looks like this:

```js
const complexPoint = {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3};

// can be written as
const point2 = (({x, y}) => ({x, y}))(complexPoint);

console.log(point2);
```

Answer (score 21):

You can do this with array destructuring, i.e.:

```
const complexPoint = [1,2];

let x, y;
[x,y] = complexPoint;
```

As for object destructuring, an equivalent syntax would not work as it would throw off the interpreter:

```
const complexPoint = {x:1,y:2};

let x, y;
{x,y} = complexPoint; // THIS WOULD NOT WORK
```

A workaround could be:

```
const complexPoint = {x:1,y:2};

let x, y;
[x,y] = [complexPoint.x, complexPoint.y];

// Or
[x,y] = Object.values(complexPoint);
```

**UPDATE:**

It appears you can destructure an object into existing variables by wrapping the assignment in parenthesis and turning it into an expression. So this should work:

```
const complexPoint = {x:1,y:2};

let x, y;
({x,y} = complexPoint); // THIS WILL WORK
```

Comment: Wrong. Object destructuring into variables *does work* (in expression context) !

Comment: The idea is not to modify x and y

Comment: @JonasWilms Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Actually you are correct. If you wrap the assignment in parenthesis, you can destructure the object into existing variables. i.e. ({x,y} = complexPoint)

Comment: notice that `;` is required on the line before the parenthesis (here you have `;` in all lines so this is good)

Answer (score 3):

It's not 100% clear to me what you want to do.

**If you want to update `point` with two properties of `complexPoint`**

You can actually destructure an object into anything that is assignable. Most often you will destructure into variables, but you can also destructure into *properties*.

Example:

```js
const point = {x: 1, y: 2};
const otherPoint = {x:3, y: 4};

   ({x: point.x, y: point.y} = otherPoint);
// ^                                     ^
// parenthesis are necessary otherwise the runtime will interpret {
// as the start of a block

console.log(point);
```

Of course this can become difficult to read the more properties you have. You can also just assign them directly, the good old fashioned way:

```js
point.x = otherPoint.x;
point.y = otherPoint.y;
```

Or with a loop:

```js
for (const prop of ['x','y']) {
  point[prop] = otherPoint[prop];
}
```

**If you want to create a new object from an existing object**

Create a helper function to "pick" the properties from the existing object. Such a function is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25553910/218196).

```js
const point = pick(otherPoint, 'x', 'y');
```

Answer (score 0):

After the destructuring, you can use the destructured data and save it as an object to another variable.

If we have this object:

```
const obj={"property":"value","property2":"value"};
```

You can destructure data from it like this:

```
const {property}=obj;
```

If we want to assign the destructured data only to another variable, We would do this:

```
const newVariable ={property};
```

Now the newVariable value will be equal to:

```
{"property":"value"}
```