# AXIOS + TS: Is there a way to use `const { data } = await axios.get(insertthinghere);` multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios

Is there a way to use `const { data } = await axios.get(insertthinghere);` multiple times?

Trying to use AXIOS to get stuff from APIs, using the code above works once however when trying to use it again, it throws an error.

`Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'data'`

Trying to change data to anything else also doesn't work.

Example of what I'm trying to do with placeholder names.

```
let api1 = "INSERTAPILINKHERE";

    if (args.length) {
      api1 += `/++${args[0]}`;
    }

    const { data } = await axios.get(api1);

    var variable1 = JSON.stringify(data);

    variable1 = variable1.replace(/\D/g, "");

    let api2 = "ANOTHERDIFFERENTAPILINK";

    if (args.length) {
      api2 += `/++${args[0]}`;
    }

    const { data2 } = await axios.get(api2);

    const parsedJSON = JSON.parse(data2);

    var valueFromJSON = parsedJSON.somevalue;
```

Comment: You don't need to _define_ the variable the second time you do it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59416204/3001761

Comment: Do this the second time: `({ data } = await axios.get(otherthinghere))`

Comment: @ShamPooSham Tried that, it worked but now I've got another problem on my hands where it seems to think the data from the second API isn't JSON, and throws `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` at me.

Comment: Put it in a function and call it multiple times? Or put it in a loop?

Comment: You might want to use multiple block scopes to avoid re-declaring the variable. Or just use a different variable name, like you already did, but then you need to change the destructuring syntax to still use the `.data` property. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904523/es6-es2015-object-destructuring-and-changing-target-variable) for how to do that, or just don't use destructuring and write an ordinary `const data2 = (await …).data;`

Comment: @Throwaway644584 you probably wanted to use JSON.parse or other way around

Comment: Figured out why my JSON won't parse correctly.

The API is giving me this back. (Variables and Values changed.)
`{"data":[{"variable":1234,"string":"Hello World.","string2":"Lorem Ipsum."}]}`
Not sure what to do with this to be honest, tried doing something similar to this but it didn't work.
`parsedJSON.data.string2`

Comment: @Throwaway644584 parsesJSON.data is an array, so you'll have to loop over that or take the first element with `[0]` if you know if only contains one element

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of `const { data } = await axios.get(…)` is called destructing and is equivalent to: `const data = (await axios.get(…)).data`.
It a shortcut take a specific field from an object. So writing this line twice is the same as defining two consts with the same name.

The solutions are:

1. Rename the variable `const { data: newName } = …`
2. Avoid using destructing and use the long way as I wrote above