# Not understanding payload in update action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am having trouble understanding in how will the payload look in the first action. Why in the first one there is `{ } and ...` , what does that give? How do I pass data into it, when I call it from a component?
In the second one, i would just pass an object, but I don't get the first one.

```js
update({ id, ...rest }) {
    return http.patch(`/test/${id}`, rest);
  },
```

```js
update(id, rest) {
    return http.patch(`/test/${id}`, rest);
  },
```

Comment: This is called [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: This should help in understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43767533/9779577

Comment: @FriedRiceEater no. It expects an object to be passed as the first argument. It ignores all other arguments. Then it assigns the object property `id` to a variable `id` and "gathers" the rest of the object properties into a variable called `rest`. `rest` will be an object.

Comment: The second example uses two parameters. No destructuring, no rest, nothing special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `update` like this.

```js
update({
  id: 123,

  // other  property
  name: 'your name',
  tel: 'your tel'
})
```

in `update`, `id`is`123`, and `rest` is `{name: 'your name',tel: 'your tel'}`

```js
function update ({ id, ...rest }) {
    console.log('id is:', id);
    console.log('rest is:', rest);
}
    
update({
    id: 123,
    
    // other  property
    name: 'your name',
    tel: 'your tel'
});
```